# Modelling peaks in regularized logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, inference, regularization

First post so please be gentle...

I am modelling events, be it default, pay, close etc., using regularized regression. I am using spline variables for time etc. Overall the model appears pretty accurate. The problem is, no matter how many knots and splines, I am struggling to accurately capture an initial steep peak and then subsequent decline in the data. 
I  have tried using extra dummies to represent the peak and this works to a point, but looks far too artificial and event rates drop of a cliff the following month. I have tried increasing/decreasing the regularization parameter, and even not regularizing the first few months, no joy.

Any thoughts on how to capture the peak would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you link to plots of your data showing the problem?

Comment: With many programs, you can specify the location of some or all of the knots.  That might help.